# Get index of two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, indexing

I have a two-dimensional array like this:

A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
I,J,K,L
M,N,O,P

I need the one-dimensional index from the two dimensions:
`f(array, 1, 2) => 6 //G`

Edited; the question wasn't clear. The solution I was looking for would be `f(a: array, x: int, y: int) = y * a[0].length + x`

Comment: Specify a language, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `index = row * width + column` to me.